# Refer to previous of previous page in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my Razor app I am trying to make back redirections to previous pages. I find good solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42228327/6485612 using `Request.Headers["Referer"]`, however, the problem is how to remember the previous backUrl of the previous page. When i want to go two pages back, I end up in a loop between two pages I was lastly on.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve to go multiple pages back?

Comment: Why don't you use `<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Return to client detail</a>` from the post you provided?

Comment: Its good solution too, however if open another web site (like youtube) while using my app and I use `history.go(-1)`, it will redirect me to the youtube page

Comment: Do you open another web site in the new tab or in the same tab?

Comment: In the same tab. I copy my apps url, then i go to youtube for example. Then i go back to my apps page and when I use history.go(-1), it redirects me to youtube.

Comment: It seems that the work is correct. [your app -> youtube -> your app] go back one step and there is youtube

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Use @Html.ActionLink("Go Back","Actio Name","Controller Name")
```

or you can use javascript adding a back button

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Back</button>
```